# restarting Oracle 23c within the docker container causes blocked listener

Tags: docker, oracle, docker-compose, database-administration

I am using the Free Oracle 23c Docker container ([see here](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/free/get-started/)) to help provision a development environment.

As part of the configuration of the environment, I am putting scripts and SQL into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup` using configuration in my docker-compose.yml file.

One of those scripts is to set the COMPATIBILITY parameter (`ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE = '19.0.0' SCOPE=SPFILE;`), which, after setting it, requires a database restart.

In a server database install, I would run my SQL to set the compatibility, followed by something like the following:

```bash
echo -e "shutdown immediate \n startup mount" | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
```

in order to restart the database.

However, when I do this in the docker container (whether I do it automatically as described above, or by manually connecting to sqlplus on the container and running the same commands), once the db has restarted the lister comes back with a blocked connection, and I can no longer connect to the database.

`docker exec -ti app_db_1 lsnrctl status` gives the following:

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Developer-Release on
> 14-SEP-2023 08:27:40
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE))) STATUS of
> the LISTENER
> ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Developer-Release Start Date
> 14-SEP-2023 08:27:37 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 2
> sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
> OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Default Service
> FREE Listener Parameter File
> /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/network/admin/listener.ora Listener
> Log File
> /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/854ac05c3c0f/listener/alert/log.xml Listening
> Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
> Services Summary... Service "FREE" has 1 instance(s).   Instance
> "FREE", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service
> "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "PLSExtProc", status
> UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The command completed
> successfully

note the `Instance "FREE", status BLOCKED` section of the output.

How can I restart the database programmatically within the container without this happening?

UPDATE - logging in and running the restart interactively shows the following:

> ORA-00201: control file version 23.0.0.0.0 incompatible with ORACLE version
> 19.0.0.0.0
> ORA-00202: control file: '/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/control01.ctl'

---

Before restarting, `lsnrctl status` returns this:

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Developer-Release on
> 14-SEP-2023 08:32:57
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE))) STATUS of
> the LISTENER
> ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Developer-Release Start Date
> 14-SEP-2023 08:32:46 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 10
> sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
> OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Default Service
> FREE Listener Parameter File
> /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/network/admin/listener.ora Listener
> Log File
> /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/05cf8b8b6d41/listener/alert/log.xml Listening
> Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
> Services Summary... Service "FREE" has 1 instance(s).   Instance
> "FREE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service
> "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "PLSExtProc", status
> UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The command completed
> successfully

Comment: I have just verified to restart the database (no startup-scripts) and the listener isn't blocking. There must be something with your startup-scripts... Use the elimination method I would suggest. If you update your question with the compatibility clause, I can check using startup-scripts.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt done. I also tried the restart interactively, and the following came up in SQLPlus: `ORA-00201: control file version 23.0.0.0.0 incompatible with ORACLE version
19.0.0.0.0
ORA-00202: control file: '/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/control01.ctl'`

Comment: So it might just be that it doesn't like changing the compatibility mode down from 23 to 19. If so, any idea how I can do that using the 23c image? Because unlike the 19c one, the 23c one is free

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `compatibility` parameter lower, only higher; so this was causing the database to not start up; and therefore the listener to be blocked